# Reading data from excel 2010 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I am not able to read data in Excel. Here is the code I am using:

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"Book1.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(xlWorksheet.Cells[i,j].ToString());
    }
}
```

I get a message box that says something about `System.__ComObject` instead of a value.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution for above, here is the code:

```
string temp = (string)(xlRange.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Value2;
MessageBox.Show(temp);
```

Answer (score 5):

Haven´t tested it, but I think it should read

```
MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i,j].ToString());
```

or alternatively

```
MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i,j].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Throwing below error "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i][j].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following function to get data as DATATABLE object for N'th sheet :

```
public DataTable GetWorkSheet(int workSheetID)
    {
        string pathOfExcelFile = fileFullName;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            excel.Application excelApp = new excel.Application();

            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false; //Don't want Excel to display error messageboxes

            excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(pathOfExcelFile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //This opens the file

            excel.Worksheet sheet = (excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(workSheetID); //Get the first sheet in the file

            int lastRow = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).Row;
            int lastColumn = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).Column;

            excel.Range oRange = sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[lastRow, lastColumn]);//("A1",lastColumnIndex + lastRow.ToString());

            oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();


            for (int i = 0; i < oRange.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("a" + i.ToString());
            }

            object[,] cellValues = (object[,])oRange.Value2;
            object[] values = new object[lastColumn];

            for (int i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    values[j] = cellValues[i, j + 1];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(values);
            }

            workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        return dt;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
MessageBox.Show(((Excel.Range)xlRange.Cells[i,j]).Value2.ToString());
```

This code works sucessfully for me.