# Getting Data From Excel File

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-office

I am trying to get data from an excel file to parse to a table in my database. Basically I am trying to read an excel file and copy all the data to a database.

I tried some different methods but did not succeed. I mainly tried to use [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

Can someone help me with this.

I am using windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting? 'Did not succeed' is not specific enough for us to assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .NET libraries for excel, they are generally easier to use, and doesn't require excel installed on target machine.

[NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) for .xls (Excel 2003 and lower), and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for xslx (2007+)

Answer (score -1):

Project -> Add Reference -> LATEST Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
And then you have this example on how to access the data in a workbook:

[Reading data from excel 2010 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873389/reading-data-from-excel-2010-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel)


I hope this is your solution.

Comment: Interop is really crap. It looks promising, but it's so crappy (usabillity, ease of development, speed!) that you are better off without it.
And there is mostly no use-case which requires Interop for excel, something like epplus can do nearly all important things.