# C# - How do I export and import data to Excel and back to Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, import, save

I've been trying this with Linq but nothing positive came up.
I understand the bases of C# and I took myself a job to make my father a program that he needs,that enters people information and saves or loads them.

Any Idea?

Comment: Linq? What else did you try? Is it winforms? Any special thing on the excel part? formulas? workbooks? special formatting? why don't you use one of the many many answers that cover the problem?? look to the right of this and see a dozen post about the issue!!

Comment: Like I didn't try that before. Do you think that if I was able to solve the problem I would ask for help?. Turn on the logic button kid

Comment: Do you think I would have asked all those question if I didn't believe you ought to tell us? In addition to the answers below there are a dozen related question to the right of this page? So what did you try and what were the problems? __'Kid'__ really?  Good luck with this attitude!

Comment: Problem is suprise suprise I can't get it to work getting the to and from excel to load in datagridview. I've tried dozens of solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You don't neeed excel on machine. I tested and I used this approach to export data to excel 1 000 000 rows

Solution is read and write excel from and to `DataTable`

https://github.com/jsegarra1971/SejExcelExport

Full example how to use it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/829389/Fast-Excel-Import-and-Export

But

You can also use that approach

1. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel [Reading data from excel 2010 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873389/reading-data-from-excel-2010-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel)
2. DocumentFormat.OpenXml and WindowsBase. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Hiii, try [this](https://www.google.de/search?q=import%20excel%20into%20gridview%20c%23&trackid=sp-006) there are much example how to import and export excel to data gridview